# PHP function to remove String without HTML tags in the given html

Tags: php, html

I have a html code:

```
<a href="#">foo</a>bar is dummy string<p>hello</p>
```

I want an output to be

```
<a href="#">foo</a><p>hello</p>
```

I am searching for PHP code to get the above result. Filter only html embedded strings to output. I know strip_tags() function will remove html tags and output only the strings.

Comment: I'd look into DOM and XPath. I'll whip up a quick demo soon

Comment: Thanks phill. Consider above codes as string like $str1 = 1st code, $output = 2nd code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take your html code in $html

```
$string = strip_tags($html); 
$final = str_replace($string , "", $html);
```

It may helps you. Someone answered the same and unfortunately he has deleted.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$html = <<<_HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<a href="#">foo</a>bar is dummy string<p>hello</p>
</body>
</html>
_HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$textNodes = $xpath->query('/html/body/a/following-sibling::text()[1]');
if ($textNodes->length) {
    $node = $textNodes->item(0);
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars($doc->saveHTML()), '</pre>';
```

Result is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body>
<a href="#">foo</a><p>hello</p>
</body></html>
```

Demo here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/akDqkj

Answer (score -1):

use `regex` to perform such replacements...